# How to concat multiple files to a single file at the same time

Tags: ant

I am trying to concat multiple files (say 15 txt files) to a single file at the same time by separate ant calls.

Say there are 15 concat() run at the same time.

However, the output file was not expected.
The data in the output file is corrupted.

Does anyone have idea to solve this problem?

Example:

```
Input 1:
a=1
b=2
c=3

Input 2:
d=4
e=5
f=6

Output:
a=1
b=2
d=4
e
c=3=5
f=6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [concat](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) task, which take a resource collection such as `filesets' as nested elements, allowing you to concatenate all the files in a single task call. Example:

```
<concat destfile="${build.dir}/output.txt">
  <fileset file="${src.dir}/input1.txt" />
  <fileset file="${src.dir}/input2.txt" />
</concat>
```

Comment: Sorry, the two input files are controlled by separated ant calls.
This solution cannot be used in my case.